# gcc-4.8 failed with error "where has __float128 gone?"

Tags: macos, gcc, build, darwin

I am trying to build GCC on a core2-apple-darwin12.3.0 i386 machine. The configure seems to go through without problems but when I invoke 'make' it returns an error.

```
In file included from ./kinds.h:75:0,
             from /gcc-4.8.0/libgfortran/libgfortran.h:232,
             from /gcc-4.8.0/libgfortran/fmain.c:4:

/gcc-4.8.0/libgfortran/kinds-override.h:40:5: error: #error "Where has __float128 gone?"

 #   error "Where has __float128 gone?"
 ^  
make[3]: *** [fmain.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgfortran] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So far I have been unable to track down a successful fix.

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53731.

Comment: I have tried the above patch without success.

Comment: If you don't need a fortran compiler, did you try specifying required languages via `--enable-languages=...` while configuring (http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to succesfully build and install the compilers for c and c++. I will write a post describing what I did.

Comment: @PhiloEpisteme, any update on that post?